# Laravel automatically setting the inverse relationship with eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Lets say I have a hasMany relationship between User and Book

like so:

```
class User extends Model {
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Book extends Model {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

If I were to eager load all users and their books it would look like this:

```
$users = User::with('books')->get();
```

This means only 2 queries are done.

1. To get all users
2. To get all books belonging to those users

That means no additional queries are done if I did:

```
$users[0]->books[0]
```

However, an additional query is done if going back the inverse, even though the result is already known:

```
$users[0]->books[0]->user
```

Is there a way to automatically set the inverse of the relationship without it doing another query?

Comment: Wow, do not do `$users[0]->books[0]`, I know it has `ArrayAccess` interface (I think) so you can use it as an array, but it is a collection, get used to `first()` or `last()`, etc... Do it Laravel way... Hope you don't use that syntax and was only for demo purpose...

Comment: Yes it was for demo purposes.

Comment: Awesome then ! You gave me a heart attack

Comment: lol it really isn't that big of a deal if you did array syntax, as it uses `ArrayAccess` interface. Of course `first()` is cleaner and returns `null` if it's an empty array.

Comment: There is nothing more demonic than accessing a Collection with array syntax...

Comment: Why do you believe that? Just a style thing, or an actual reason.

Comment: Style, it is just horrible when you have `->first()` or `->all()` or `->find()` and more available.

Comment: Yeah but let's say you want the 3rd item. Surely `$users[2]` is better.

Comment: If you want explicitly the 3rd item, then you have some logic wrong as why would you have 1, 2, 3, 4, etc and want the 3rd ? Only get 3rd from DB and done... else you are going to iterate all of them...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading).

```
$users = User::with('books','books.user')->get();
```

By doing so, you don't query database anymore when you call for example `$users[0]->books[0]->user`

Comment: Doesn't this do 3 queries instead of 2.